# Making my own slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

I am making a slider and am having a few issues.

1) On first slide the animation doesn't animate.

2) The spacing for the last box is off in the beggining but as the slider progresses it corrects.

3) Sometimes the animations have some stuttering.

I have put this in a codepen here:

http://codepen.io/mpaccione/pen/MyJNxM

Any advice is much appreciated. I am unsure why these issues are arising. I am using css transitions for the animation and javascript/jquery to change the css/dom/calcs.

CODE

```
<style type="text/css">
    html,body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #888;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #slider {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    #slider ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        top: 50%;
        position: relative;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #slider li {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .sliderContainer {
        width: 60%;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: white;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        position: relative;
    }

</style>

    <div class="sliderContainer">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>
                <li style="background-color: red">a</li>
                <li style="background-color: green">b</li>
                <li style="background-color: blue">c</li>
                <li style="background-color: orange">d</li>
                <li style="background-color: purple">e</li>
                <li style="background-color: yellow">f</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("ready", function(){

    var slider = $("#slider"),
        sliderWidth = slider.outerWidth(true),
        img = slider.find("li"),
        imgWidth = img.outerWidth(true),
        imgCount = img.length,
        imgSize = sliderWidth/imgCount,
        imgHorMargin = parseFloat(img.css("margin-left")) + parseFloat(img.css("margin-right")),
        imgVerMargin = parseFloat(img.css("margin-bottom")) + parseFloat(img.css("margin-top")),
        imgSizeX = (imgSize-imgHorMargin),
        imgSizeY = (imgSize-imgVerMargin);

    slider.find("li").css({"width": imgSizeX, "height": imgSizeY});


    (function slideActivate(){
        setTimeout(function loop(){
            slider.css("transition-duration", "0.5s");
            slider.css("left",-imgSize);
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("timeout2");
                firstImage = slider.find("li")[0];
                firstImage.remove();
                slider.css("transition-duration", "0s");
                slider.css("left", "0px");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("timeout3");
                    slider.find("ul").append(firstImage);
                    requestAnimationFrame(slideActivate);
                }, 100);
            }, 500);
        }, 2000);
    })();

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the margin issue was do to the browser rendering space as the elements were inline-block. Browsers add uneditable spacing.

The best solution I have found is to make the parent of the ul to have font-size:0.

The second issue was the first slide not animating which was because I did not have an initial css left value set to animate from.

Comment: Browsers don't add uneditable spacing. You do. Remove the white space between the tags and the problem will disappear.

Comment: I think its a design mistake to have a browser render whitespace between the end of one tag and the beginning of the next. When I say uneditable I am meaning more along the lines of I cannot set the value like I would a css value.